# ng-if not comparing $index in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

In my code I want to print only **first word**  from the array, and I am using **ng-if** condition.

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="Word in Words">
   <div ng-if="$index === 0" class="preview">{{Word}}- {{$index}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.Words = ['Mon','Tue','Wed'];
}
```

As you can see I use `ng-if="$index === 0"` then print div value but it want work, don't know why?

Example:http://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/twvy0j4a/3/

Comment: In latest version it works http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/7mq2jboy/ Why you are still use version 1.0.3

Comment: @satpal yes you are right my version is 1.0.3 problem solved

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**ngIf comes from angular verison 1.2.1 but you used 1.0.3**  So your ng-if is not worked. If you upgrade the angular version to latest it works charmly.

Otherwise my suggestion to use **ngShow** directive

Use `ng-show` in this context and simply use `$first` for show first element in the array

```
 <div ng-show="$first" class="preview">{{Word}}- {{$index}}</div>
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/twvy0j4a/6/)

**When we use ngIf and ngShow:**

The **ngIf** directive removes or recreates a portion of the DOM tree based on an {expression}

The **ngShow** directive shows or hides the given HTML element based on the expression provided to the ngShow attribute

Answer (score 2):

An even better way would be to use `$first` instead of comparing `$index`

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="Word in Words">
        <div ng-show="$first" class="preview">{{Word}}- {{$index}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the latest version of AngularJS, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Just use ng-show it wil work :)

```
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="Word in Words">
       <div ng-show="$index == 0" class="preview">{{Word}}- {{$index}}</div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: this also good idea but actually i want to apply  some condition on it so i want ng-if and as @ Satpal my proble is solved