# $index of ng-repeat not incremented inside ng-if

Tags: javascript, angularjs

`$index` value not increment inside `ng-if` block.

```html
<div ng-repeat="household in census.households track by $index">
    <div ng-if="household.ask_for_tobacco">
       <input id="tobacco_{{$index}}" type="checkbox" ng-model="member.smoker">
       <label for="tobacco_{{$index}}"></label>
     </div>
</div>
```

In above block, I am using ng-repeat and `ng-if` inside it. I am following condition `ng-if` and setting element id with `$index`. Element ID is being set `0` every time, rather than incremented to `1,2,3...`

If `ng-if` removed, it works without fail. So anyone has used and faced same issue. Please give me solution.

Comment: try `$parent.$index` because `ng-if` create a new scope

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem, i put in fiddle to test [check here](http://jsfiddle.net/2Lk2ve2v/14/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ng-if not comparing $index in ng-repeat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30619023/ng-if-not-comparing-index-in-ng-repeat)

Comment: @fabiosilvalima It is probably because it is a version issue.

Comment: Create a demo that reproduces problem. It clearly works in demo above

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `ng-if` creates its own scope which then interferes with your access to the scope of the iteration that is created by `ng-repeat`.

Because you can't use `ng-show`, my suggestion is that you apply a filter to your `ng-repeat` like this:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="household in households | filter: { ask_for_tobacco: true }">
    <input id="tobacco_{{$index}}" type="checkbox">
    <label for="tobacco_{{$index}}">index {{ $index }} id = {{ household.id }}</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

See working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/m25afg12/9/

Comment: Can not use ng-show, as it creates input even though condition false which can cause issue in form submission

Comment: Hmm. What if you did an ng-repeat on census.households.filter(h => h.ask_for_tobacco) then?

Answer (score 0):

you can use $parent.$index
 late though for ans :D